# Program crashing when reading blank line - c

Tags: c, file

I recently started working with files and i'm experiencing an error. I have a txt. file with the following strings:

```
a|10

b|5
```

My problem is when im reading the blank line, somehow it crashes even when i have the condition in the code. When debugging i can see that the line receives a "\n" but program doesnt recognize it in the condition and it crashes.

```
void delete_prod(void)
{
FILE *pfile;
char line[21];
char *buffer;
char *ptr;
char produto_nome[21];
char produto_quantidade[21];

char quantidade_nova[21];
char teste[21];
char barra_linha[]="\n";

buffer = (char *) malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
memset(buffer, 0, 1000*sizeof(char));
ptr = buffer;

printf("material:");
scanf("%s",teste);

pfile = fopen("registos.txt", "r");

while(!feof(pfile))
{
    int i=0;
    for(i; i<21;i++)
    {
        line[i] = 0;
    }
    fgets(line, 21, pfile);
    if(line != NULL || line != "\n")
    {
        strcpy(produto_nome, strtok(line ,"|"));
        strcpy(produto_quantidade, strtok(NULL, "|"));

        if((strcmp(produto_nome,teste) == 0))
        {
            //DO THE REST OF THE WORK HERE
            printf("HERE");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR");
        }
    }
}
fclose(pfile);
}
```

Have been researching here but didnt find anything that fixes my problem. 
Thanks in advance and i hope i made myself clear explaining the problem.

Comment: `line != NULL` is _always_ true.  Use `if (fgets(line, sizeof line, pfile) &&  line[0] != '\n') {`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: yeah that was one of my problem. Thx!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider fgets for all input.
`strpbrk` can be used to see if the line contains a `|`.
`sscanf` can parse the line to see if there are two values.

```
void delete_prod(void)
{
    FILE *pfile;
    char line[21];
    char *buffer;
    char *ptr;
    char produto_nome[21];
    char produto_quantidade[21];

    char quantidade_nova[21];
    char teste[21];
    char barra_linha[]="\n";

    buffer = (char *) malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    memset(buffer, 0, 1000*sizeof(char));
    ptr = buffer;

    printf("material:");
    fgets ( teste, sizeof teste, stdin);
    teste[strcspn ( teste, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline

    pfile = fopen("registos.txt", "r");

    while( fgets ( line, sizeof line, pfile))
    {
        if( strpbrk ( line, "|"))//the line contains a |
        {
            //sscanf for two items
            result = sscanf ( line, "%20[^|]|%20s", procuto_nome, produto_quantidade);

            if(result == 2) {
                if((strcmp(produto_nome,teste) == 0))
                {
                    //DO THE REST OF THE WORK HERE
                    printf("HERE");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("ERROR");
                }
            }
            else {
                printf ( "ERROR line did not contain two values\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf ( "ERROR line does not contain |\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(pfile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition of checking blank line is not correctly coded.

**Change**

`line != "\n"`

**to**

`line[0] != '\n'`

Because this condition was not correct, it was always getting satisfied. Later inside the `if` block `strtok` was returning null because there was no pipe symbol in the empty line. So effectively, you were passing null to the `strcpy` function which was crashing your program.